# Late Schengen exit visa declined experience

Tags: visas, schengen

Can someone share their experience of leaving schengen area late (specifically Budapest)?

I found that if you leave Schengen after your Visa expires, this is going to be recorded in their database and you are subject to a fine up to 500EUR. With the late exit record, your future applications for visa 'can be declined' (exact words the embassy representative used when explaining it to me). This sounds a little tricky because I don't understand what 'can be declined' means.

Can someone share their experience with the fine, passport check when leaving the country late and future visa applications with the late exit record?

Comment: Your applications for visa can always "be declined". Showing that you cannot be trusted with obeying the limits stated in the visa only makes it a lot more probable.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. Mostly interested to hear if people who tried applying after leaving late got declined their applications. Also curious how long the record lasts

Comment: The fine will be decided by the country where you leave. The next visa will be decided by the main destination of the next trip.

Comment: Further to @o.m.'s comment, it's hard to generalize, because there are so many possible combinations of those countries, and the outcome depends on the national law of the two countries in addition to any effect that individual actors may have (whether because of explicit discretion or implicit bias).